# How do I create and instantiate a new custom field in hook_install() of the module that declares that custom field?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

My module defines a custom field type with `hook_field_info()`. In `hook_install()` of this module, I am trying to create new fields and instances of this custom field type:

```
function my_module_install() {

  if (!field_info_field('my_field')) {
    $field = array(
      'field_name' => 'my_field',
      'type' => 'custom_field_type',
      'cardinality' => 1
    );
    field_create_field($field);
  }
}
```

The code crashes at `field_create_field($field)`:

```
WD php: FieldException: Attempt to create a field of unknown type custom_field_type. in field_create_field() (line 110 of                                            [error]
/path/to/modules/field/field.crud.inc).
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /path/to/drush/includes/output.inc:37) bootstrap.inc:1255                             [warning]
FieldException: Attempt to create a field of unknown type <em class="placeholder">custom_field_type</em>. in field_create_field() (line 110 of /path/to/modules/field/field.crud.inc).
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to enable a module that defines field types and attempts to use those same field types in its `hook_install()`, before it's enabled. Drupal's field info cache is not rebuilt before `hook_install()` is run, so Drupal does not know about the field types in your module when you're trying to create your field.

To get around this, manually rebuild the field info cache by calling `field_info_cache_clear()` before `field_create_field($field)`:

```
if (!field_info_field('my_field')) {
  field_info_cache_clear();

  $field = array(
    'field_name' => 'my_field',
    'type' => 'custom_field_type',
    'cardinality' => 1
  );
  field_create_field($field);
}
```